# password reset email is not receiving?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, password-recovery

import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth"
const Forgotpassword = (email)=>{
email.toString();
if(!email)
{
Alert.alert("please enter Email");
}
else{
console.log(email)
//return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth,email)
return auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(()=>{
showToast();
}).catch((error)=>{
Alert.alert('Error:', error.message)
})
}
}

Comment: Edit the question and have your code formatted.

Comment: If there's no error when you call `sendPasswordResetEmail`, the email almost certainly was sent correctly. Check your spam folder, as recently a lot of the auth emails from Firebase are showing up there for users.